# String operations in c# asp.net with respect to GridView and DataSource

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding, gridview

C# -- ASP.Net -- Webforms

I have a database **X**  (Column1 - PrimaryKey)

```
`[Column1(int)] -- [Column2(string)]`

          `[12] -- [ab]`

          `[34] -- [cd]`

          `[56] -- [xy]`

          `[78] -- [ac]`
```

I have another database **Y** (Column1 - PrimaryKey)

```
`[Column1(int)] -- [Column2(string)]`

          `[A1] -- [12,34,56]`
```

I have a GridView say GV in which I'm displaying the **A1**'s column2 from database **Y**:

as

-- Edit -- Delete -- `ab`

-- Edit -- Delete -- `cd`

-- Edit -- Delete -- `xy`

with **edit** and **delete** option on each row,

where on each **edit**, I need to update the **string** `[12,34,56]` of `[A1]` in database **y**.

Say I'm editing the first row of GridView **ab** as **ac** which maps to the 4th row in databse **X**. My result should be `[78,34,56]` in `[A1]` of database **Y**.

Apologies, if post is duplicate..

Comment: Please forgive me for being dense, but try as I might, I just don't understand your database table description at all. Could you please clarify/provide more detail?

Comment: @DavidW Hope the edit would be clear. Thanks.